# How do I utilize the first Session window in tmux

Tags: shell-script, tmux

I would like to use `figlet` on the very first window of the `tmux` session that I have created using the following script:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 # log the date time in a log file
 date >> ~/logFiles/session.log

 # start a session called TWIN
 /usr/bin/tmux new-session -d -s TWIN

 # stay on even when the script crashes
 /usr/bin/tmux set-option set-remain-on-exit-on

 # Start the python script
 /usr/bin/tmux new-window -d -n 'bucket' -t TWIN:1 'sleep 20; 
                                             sudo /home/pi/bin/bucket.py'

 # Start checker script in the folder
 /usr/bin/tmux new-window -d -n 'checker' -t TWIN:2 'cd /home/pi/incoming; 
                                                     figlet Incoming;
                                               /home/pi/incoming/checker'

 # Start the Bootstraploader script
/usr/bin/tmux new-window -d -n 'bsl' -t TWIN:3 'cd /home/pi/bsl; 
                                         figlet BootStrapLoader;
                                               /home/pi/bin/bsl'

exit 0
```

The above script generates the following Windows:

`0:sh | 1: bucket | 2: checker| 3: bsl`

the `figlet` letters work well in the `window:2` and `window:3` how ever I want to add a `figlet` on the `0:sh`

I tried adding the following line:

```
/usr/bin/tmux new-window -d -n 'welcome' -t TWIN:0 'figlet hello'
```

in the above mentioned script but the output was the following:

```
  ./createSession 
  unknown option: set-remain-on-exit-on
  create window failed: index in use: 0
```

I also tried the following:

```
 /usr/bin/tmux new-session -d -s TWIN 'figlet hello'
```

but the output is :

```
 can't establish current session
```

I would somehow like to use `0:sh` which is created due to the creating `new-session` command.

Is there a way I can use this? since everytime I log into the session using `tmux a` I get to see a blank session which isn't so *cool*

### Note:

This is what `figlet Incoming` would look like (for those who do not use it)

```
 ___                           _             
|_ _|_ __   ___ ___  _ __ ___ (_)_ __   __ _ 
 | || '_ \ / __/ _ \| '_ ` _ \| | '_ \ / _` |
 | || | | | (_| (_) | | | | | | | | | | (_| |
|___|_| |_|\___\___/|_| |_| |_|_|_| |_|\__, |
                                       |___/
```

Comment: just to keep the question focused, I assume the first line is a typo for "#!/bin/bash" vs "!#/bin/bash" ?

Comment: oops sorry for that ! @JeffSchaller but usually we do write shebang lines as `#!/bin/bash` right?